# Change class in angularJS in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

I have two css classed `triangle` and `triangleo`

```
<div class="triangle" ng-repeat="chatdata in chats">
<p>{{chatdata.msg}}</p>
<p> {{chatdata.time}}</p>
</div>
```

So if chatdata.usrId == 123 class should be `triangle` else `triangleo`

Comment: is it ionic v1 or 2? angularjs is used in v1..

Comment: I am using ionic1

Comment: ok.. please use only relevant tags..

Comment: my bad I totally missed that

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe, i think suraj was humble enough to add a *please*, it did not look rude to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use `ng-class`

```
<div ng-class="chatdata.usrId === 123 ? 'triangle' : 'triangleo'" ng-repeat="chatdata in chats">
   <p>{{chatdata.msg}}</p>
   <p> {{chatdata.time}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.. long live man .. verifying it in 7 minutes